# Multiple Inserts into Table with same primary key at once - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I want to insert multiple values with same primary key in a table at once.

How it can be done in postgresql.

I am fetching the primary key from another table as well multiple values are also from another table.

I am trying out this.

```
INSERT INTO ceh_grouped_alert_map (grp_id, alert_id, created_date) 
SELECT (select grp_id from ceh_grouped_alerts where alert_name = 'ABC') id, x
FROM unnest((select alert_id from ceh_alerts where alert_name = 'ABC')) x, '2017-03-17 10.00.00.000'
```

But not able to do so.

Comment: primary key was supposed to unique, you cant insert multiple rows with same primary key. you must drop the primary key, add another column with serial type or something and create primary key using that new column

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)